# CodeIgniter Error 1064: Latitude and Longitude query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query which works in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT *, 
    ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(21.161908) ) 
    * cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) 
    * cos( radians( `longitude` ) - radians(-86.85152790000001) ) 
    + sin ( radians(21.161908) ) 
    * sin( radians( `latitude` ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM _results 
HAVING distance < 30 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

and I'm trying to execute in CodeIgniter with this:

```
$this->select("* , ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(21.161908) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-86.85152790000001) ) + sin ( radians(21.161908) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance ");
$this->db->having('distance < 30');
$this->db->order_by('distance');
$this->db->limit(20,0);
```

But with this I get this error:

> Error Number: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL Syntax... to user near '*, (6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(21.161908) ) * cos( radians(latitude) )

Anyone have idea with this error?

**Note**: I realized a previous query before this.

Comment: _"I realized a previous query before this."_ - Can you elaborate on what you mean by this please?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$this->db->select()` instead of `$this->select()`.

I had a same type query like this

```
$this->db->select("*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance");                         
$this->db->having('distance <= ' . $miles);                     
$this->db->order_by('distance');                    
$this->db->limit(20, 0);
```

which is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Working perfect for me.

```
$this->db->select("SELECT *,ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $Lat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )* COS( RADIANS( $Lat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $Long )) ) * 6380 AS `distance`");
            $this->db->from('_results');
            $this->db->where("ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 < 5");
            $this->db->orderby('distance');
            $this->db->limit(20,0);
            return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this

```
$this->db->query("SELECT *, 
    ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(21.161908) ) 
    * cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) 
    * cos( radians( `longitude` ) - radians(-86.85152790000001) ) 
    + sin ( radians(21.161908) ) 
    * sin( radians( `latitude` ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM _results 
HAVING distance < 30 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function lat_long($lat,$long){
  
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) * cos( radians( `longitude` ) - radians($long) ) + sin ( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( `latitude` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table HAVING distance < 30 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");     
 return $query->result();

  }
```